# How do I loop through elements in two bash arrays at the same time

Tags: bash, mongodump

I have a bash script that should execute mongodump on multiple databases within a single mongo instance.
The script should *dynamically* inject the Mongo-URIs and backup filenames as below :

```
mongodump --uri=$endpoint --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/$filename.gz
```

When the script runs its facing an error - it appears its not injecting the variables correctly :

```
dump.sh
Starting-BACKUP
dump.sh
platforms-2022-10-25-19:05:20
sports-2022-10-25-19:05:20
mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/platforms
mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/sports
2022-10-25T19:05:20.392+0000    Failed: error creating intents to dump: error getting collections for database `platformsmongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/sports`: (InvalidNamespace) Invalid database name: 'platformsmongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/sports'
2022-10-25T19:05:50.409+0000    Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp [::1]:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
Database backup was successful
```

Both the Mongo-URIs and backup filenames are being populated from arrays as below :

```
#declare -a BACKUP_NAMES=()
#declare -a BACKUP_ENDPOINTS=()
#declare –a DATABASES=()
#declare –a RAW_DBNAMES=()
#declare –a DATABASES=()

DATABASES+=("platforms")
DATABASES+=("sports")
BACKUP_RETURN_CODE=${?}
MONGODB_URI="mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/"
NOW="$(date +"%F")-$(date +"%T")"

#array for raw db names
for DATABASE in "${DATABASES[@]}"; 
  do
  RAW_DBNAMES+=("$DATABASE")
done

#array for constructing backup filenames
for DATABASE in "${DATABASES[@]}"; 
  do
  #echo $DATABASE
  BACKUP_NAMES+=("$DATABASE")
done

#construct backup filenames
cnt=${#BACKUP_NAMES[@]}
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
    BACKUP_NAMES[i]="${BACKUP_NAMES[i]}-$NOW"
    echo "${BACKUP_NAMES[i]}"
done

#construct db endpoints
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
    uri="$MONGODB_URI${RAW_DBNAMES[i]}"
    echo "$uri"
    BACKUP_ENDPOINTS+=$uri
done

#pass BACKUP_ENDPOINTS & BACKUP_FILENAMES to mongodump
for ((i=0; i<${#BACKUP_NAMES[@]}; i++)); 
    do 
    mongodump --uri="${BACKUP_ENDPOINTS[$i]}" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/"${BACKUP_NAMES[$i]}".gz
done

  #If the return code is non-zero then the backup was not successful
  if [[ 0 != ${BACKUP_RETURN_CODE} ]]
   then
   echo "Database backup has failed"
   exit ${BACKUP_RETURN_CODE}
else
   echo "Database backup was successful"
fi
exit 0
```

*As a check I used these two *sample arrays* and I have verified that I can indeed loop through two arrays* at the same time although this particular example is concatenating the elements (Is this how it works in general?):

```
array1=( 1 2 3 )
array2=("toronto""new york")
for ((i=0; i<${#array1[@]}; i++));  
do echo "${array1[$i]}${array2[$i]}"; 
done
```

but I am not sure why in my case the strings are concatenating so wrongly.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Replace `""` with `" "` and add a space between `echo` and `"`"?

Comment: @Cyrus thanks , I added that as an example . That particular script is working and I can loop through the two arrays' elements . My issue is on the arrays  BACKUP_NAMES and BACKUP_ENDPOINTS .

Comment: Change `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS+=$uri` to `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS+=($uri)`. Or better yet, `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS+=("$uri")`

Comment: Or, since the elements of `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS` are supposed to correspond to the elements of `RAW_DBNAMES`, use `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS[i]="$MONGODB_URI${RAW_DBNAMES[i]}"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson where should I use that ?

Comment: @Golide Inside the `#construct db endpoints` loop. The current way you're constructing `BACKUP_ENDPOINTS` inside that loop is just appending strings into a single element. Replacing it with either what rici suggested or what I suggested should fix that part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple arrays create just one and rearrange it like this:

```
arr=(
#   id item         product   
    1  apple        juice
    2  banana       smuzi
    3 'raw potato'  chips
#   ...
)

N=${#arr[*]} # number of items in array
C=3          # number of 'columns'
```

Then loop over it like so:

```
for ((i=0; i<$N; i+=$C)); {

    read id item product <<< "${arr[@]:$i:$C}"

    echo "id: $id"
    echo "item: $item"
    echo "product: $product"
    echo '-----------------'
}
```

Result:

```
id: 1
item: apple
product: juice
-----------------
id: 2
item: banana
product: smuzi
-----------------
id: 3
item: raw
product: potato chips
-----------------
```

p.s. check out [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/DDT/blob/master/ddt.sh) backup script for example it's for psql but probably could be useful.

Comment: how would you populate the 'table' dynamically though. Because I have hardcoded values here only for demo. The arrays will in reality be populated dynamically .

Comment: Like this: arr+=`( 4 cucumber salad )`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it turned i was instantiating the BACKUP_ENDPOINTS array the wrong way.

This is the correct way :

```
#construct db endpoints
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
    # uri="$MONGODB_URI${RAW_DBNAMES[i]}"
    # echo "$uri"
    # BACKUP_ENDPOINTS+=$uri  THIS IS WRONG !!!
    BACKUP_ENDPOINTS[i]="$MONGODB_URI${RAW_DBNAMES[i]}"
done

for ENDPOINT in "${BACKUP_ENDPOINTS[@]}"; do
  echo "$ENDPOINT"
done

#pass BACKUP_ENDPOINTS & BACKUP_FILENAMES to mongodump
for ((i=0; i<${#BACKUP_NAMES[@]}; i++)); 
    do 
    mongodump --uri="${BACKUP_ENDPOINTS[$i]}" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/"${BACKUP_NAMES[$i]}".gz
done
```